# PHPUnit binary installed by Composer uses system provided ResultPrinter and fails

Tags: doctrine, phpunit, phpstorm, classloader

I have a Laravel project which requires PHPUnit >= 9.5 and installs the PHPUnit binary as part of the Composer dependencies. Additionally, PHPUnit is installed by the system with version 8.5.11 (I use Gentoo). So, I have

```
~/project-dir # /usr/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.5.11 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

~/project-dir # ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

In line with that the PHP class `PHPUnit\Util\Log\TeamCity` and the interface `PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter` exists twice:

```
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Log/TeamCity.php
/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php

./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Log/TeamCity.php
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php
```

If I try to run PHPUnit from my IDE I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/localhost/lychee/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /var/www/localhost/lychee/phpunit.xml --filter Tests\\Feature\\AlbumTest --test-suffix AlbumTest.php /var/www/localhost/lychee/tests/Feature --teamcity
Testing started at 13:05 ...
PHP Fatal error:  Class PHPUnit\Util\Log\TeamCity cannot extend from interface PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Log/TeamCity.php on line 378
```

The problem is rather obvious. The IDE invokes the newer version of PHPUnit from the Composer installation, but then PHP tries to load the system-provided `ResultPrinter` instead of using the class which has been installed by Composer.

My IDE is PhpStorm.

How do I fix that problem?

Comment: If correct Composer autoloader is already used... then for me it looks like the wrong PHPUnit classes are already referenced/known to PHP by that time. try that: PHPUnit supports bootstrap file: see if that file gets executed (and when). If it executes fine (that would mean that no problmatic PHPUnit classes are loaded yet), then use `get_declared_classes` and see if PHP knows those PHPUnit classes by that point or not. if not -- perhaps there is another autoloader  or it loads from PHP's `include_path` -- if so, try removing that global PHPUnit path from there.

Comment: **P.S.** What about uninstalling the global PHPUnit altogether? No global install no issue with version collisions. If it cannot be uninstalled -- what about upgrading to the same version as this project?

Comment: Apart from uninstalling as suggested already, my question would be how/who installed the global version and for what it is required. If it is in use, it might be as easy as updating it. If it is not in use, it is perhaps sane to remove it. And that are only two prominent options, so sharing more details about the configuration may help you solve this in a straight forward manner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the local (relative to your project) PHPUnit... in the config look for the path and change it to be your project's PHPUnit executable...

[image]

Comment: That's not the problem. As you also can see from the copied command line, the IDE uses the correct PHPunit executable, the correct configuation XML and also the correct `Autoloader.php` which is created by Composer.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using ? I think that is the problem maybe, as everything else looks correct. Also, try one more thing, instead of having `"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"` or similar, try to fix the version to any before `9.5` as I saw there are some problems with it, try `"phpunit/phpunit": "~9.4"` or even `9.3` and see if it is solved (don't do `^9.3` but `~9.3`).